# Transparent background on system::windows::forms::form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, background, transparency

I have a System::Windows::Forms::Form and i'm trying to set the background to transparent.
This form contains others components and have a background image.

I try many solutions i have see on internet but nothing works.

- set form opacity to 0 -> Make the whole form become transparent.
- use colors::transparent -> Doesn't seems to work
- use TransparencyKey -> Doesn't seems to work too ...
- override OnPaintBackground or OnPaint event -> events doesn't seems to be called ...

Illustration code:

```
    public ref class Form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
         public: Form(void) {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         public: void InitializeComponent(void)
         {
             SetStyle(ControlStyles::SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
             this->TransparencyKey = System::Drawing::Color::Fuchsia;
             this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Fuchsia;
             // or ...
             this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
         }

         protected: virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)override {}
         protected: virtual void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)override {}
    }
```

Thanks for your help.
Cyrbil

Edit:

Problem solved, first for the override, it's:

```
protected: virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ e)override {}
protected: virtual void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs^ e)override {}
```

i just forget the ^.
Then, i don't know why but i started a new project and try the others methods and it has works fine. So from now i use this new project and everythings fine. I guess it's just Visual C++ who had some random problems.

Comment: Do *not* edit InitializeComponent(), it is auto-generated by the designer.  Anything you write there will randomly disappear when the designer regenerates the code.  Move the code to the constructor, **after** the InitializeComponent() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, first for the override, it's:

```
protected: virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ e)override {}
protected: virtual void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs^ e)override {}
```

i just forget the ^. Then, i don't know why but i started a new project and try the others methods and it has works fine. So from now i use this new project and everythings fine. I guess it's just Visual C++ who had some random problems.